# Giving Variadic Template Pack as function specification

Tags: templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-functions, variable-templates

I'm trying to create a function that has  a template pack specialization  (it has no parameters) and it prints a message, until the last one where function specialization makes it print something else, and stop.
As I'm really bad explaining , here I post the code of what I'm trying to do:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr void UpdateStuff()
{
    std::cerr << "I am the last one :D" << std::endl;

}
template< typename T ,typename... TT>
constexpr void UpdateStuff()
{



    std::cerr << "I am NOT the last one :D";

    UpdateStuff<TT...>();

}
int main()
{


    UpdateStuff<int,double>(); // Should only print text twice
    std::cin.get();

    return 1;
}
```

As a first note , **I know this does not work**, `UpdateStuff<TT...>();` it yields an ambigous call to overloaded function , I've managed to get it working  by giving the function `UpdateStuff()` parameters like `UpdateStuff(T first, TT... second)` and the specialization only one `UpdateStuff(T first)` but I want to know if this is possible without function parameters , I'll give a summary of my questions:

- I dont completely understand why `UpdateStuff<TT...>();` doesn't work, if TT is just `double` at compile-time why doesnt it use the first function?
- Is it possible to do what I am trying to accomplish without function parameters?

Thanks in advance , and if you don't understand something related to my question I'd be grateful to explain it better,and sorry  for my poor english.

Comment: My guess is that `UpdateStuff<double>();` would match both overloads of the `UpdateStuff` function as `TT` will be deduced there as an empty pack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

But take in count that `typename ... TT` is "zero or more typenames", so calling `UpdateStaff<double>()` both version of `UpdateStaff()` are ok.

You can, by example, impose a second type in the not final version; something like this

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... TT>
constexpr void UpdateStuff()
{
    std::cerr << "I am NOT the last one :D";

    UpdateStuff<T2, TT...>();
}
```